# Indexeddb search all orders with a particular field

Tags: indexeddb

I have looked and looked everywhere but IndexedDb is not very famous it turns out. I have an objectstore called orders with an auto-generated key with each order's structure like:

```
{"dealername":"something","dealerid":num,"totalbill":num,"items":[{},{}]}
```

Now as the objectstore orders can have multiple orders with the same dealerid, how can I get all orders with a particular dealerid?

Sorry for a noob question though, I come from a SQL background.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an index on dealerid.
2. Open a cursor on the dealerid index and iterate.

Here is some very simple code to get you started:

```
function onUpgradeNeeded(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;

  var orderStore = db.createObjectStore('orders', ...);

  // Create the index on dealerid here
  orderStore.createIndex('dealeridindex', 'dealerid');
}

function queryOrdersByDealerID(db, id, onOrder, onComplete) {
  var tx = db.transaction('orders');
  tx.onComplete = onComplete;
  var orders = tx.objectStore('orders');
  var index = orders.index('dealeridindex');
  var request = index.openCursor(id);
  // You could also do this, if you wanted, it is identical:
  // var request = index.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(id));

  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if(!cursor) return;
    onOrder(cursor.value);
    cursor.continue();
  };
}

// Now to use it:
var openRequest = indexedDB.open('dbname', version);

// Attach our upgrade handler that gets called when higher version found
openRequest.onupgradeneeded = onUpgradeNeeded;

// Now do a query
openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  // event.target === openRequest === this
  // use whatever you prefer, e.g. this.result or openRequest.result
  var openDatabaseConnection = event.target.result;

  var someId = 5;

  function handleOrder(order){
    console.log('Order %o', order);
  }

  function whenAllMatchingOrdersIterated(event) {
    console.log('Finished iterating over orders');
  }

  // 'execute' the query
  queryOrdersByDealerID(openDatabaseConnection, someId,
    handleOrder, whenAllMatchingOrdersIterated);
}
```